# Is "those information" valid, or is it "this information"?

Tags: word-usage

I know information does not have a plural form (syntaxically talking), which leads me to the following problem:

> The username and password are missing. I need [this/those] information.

I feel like the right term would be "this", even though we are asking for several details... but I'm not sure at all.

Comment: _I need this information_ or _I need those pieces of information_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'This': 'information' is the noun for which 'this' is used as the demonstrative pronoun. Since information- is singular, this - is too,  no matter what the information  consists of.

Comment: "This information" is actually the direct object, not the subject.

Comment: Specifically, *information* is a [mass noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun).

Comment: Unless you use *data* which is plural. Though it's always felt awkward to me to say "*data are*." It should be a mass noun too.

Comment: @Martin Krzywinski It's rare for _data_ to be used as other than a mass noun taking singular agreement, in spite of its etymology.

Answer (score 1):

The adjective or article  "this" modifies "information," a singular, so "this" is correct.  It assumes that the reader knows that "information" is referring to "username and password."

If instead you wish to use "this/those" as pronouns, you might write something like:

> The username and password are missing. I need these right away.

Answer (score 0):

I have been teaching it as 'this information' for more than 20 years but just heard a British reporter on Bloomberg say 'these informations' and l had to look it up. There are actually many examples of 'these information' online (and my autocorrect ironically wanted to change that to 'these informations'!!! Lol)

Answer (score -2):

How about using "such information", instead?

Comment: You should show how this fits the example used in the question.

Comment: Please don't answer a question with a question. Be bold! Make a statement, but **back that statement up** with corroboration and examples if necessary.